# Community wiki for "Websites that allow communication between people: List"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The question [Websites that allow communication between people: List](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2283/800) asks for a list of websites. Should we turn this into a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/340816)? I think we haven't used this format yet on LLSE.

Comment: Relevant: [meta stackexchange discussion on list questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366)

Answer (score 3):

Using Community Wiki was at one time considered the proper way to handle these "list questions" on SE. That time was several years ago. The more modern approach is more often simply not to allow such questions. I agree with this, and think that particular question should be closed. It's not only a list question, with literally thousands (or more) proper answers. The correct answers change daily as new web sites are created, and old ones closed. It's not our job to catalog such sites. Google does that pretty well already.

A better approach to such questions, which is taken on many sites, is to create a list of common/popular resources on meta.  [Spanish.SE has recently renewed this effort](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/12).

A (small) list of such sites might fit on such a page.  Before we jump to that conclusion, though, I'd suggest we open that specific idea for discussion at large.  We may want one post per language, rather than just a single post.  Or maybe we want a single post, with sections per language?  And maybe this community does want such a post on the main site rather than meta, etc.  I encourage you (or anyone) to put forth a proposal for this here on meta.  If nobody else does, I might do it myself when time permits.

Comment: I see. Can you also explain why the statement that is not our job to maintain such list is not seen as a contradiction of having such a list on Meta? Also, if we have such lists at all, I would assume that their proper place is on the "normal" site instead of Meta. See e.g. [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/12854).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: Good question... I think my problem with the original question is that it was impossibly broad (literally, a list answering it would include any web site with email or chat functionality--including Gmail, Facebook, and Grindr). I have edited the original question to be more specific, and also not to solicit a list.

Comment: Having said that, if we wish to maintain a list (whether in meta or on the main site), it should be sufficiently narrowly defined that we don't have an infinite list of "sites with chat features".

Comment: Apparently, I had read a narrower interpretation into that question: sites specifically for language learners where they can communicate - esp. through audio, possibly also with video - with other language learners (cf. tandem learning) and/or teachers. Anyway, let' see what other people think.